# Port 80 doesn't work

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, ubuntu-14.04, netstat, port-80

I have a website in my ubuntu server 14.04, with apache2 server, and untils fews days go the site works fine but, today if I digit www.mydomain.com from my internal network it works but, if I try with external network my site doesn't work and I have this error: "This webpage is not available. Internet could not load the webpage because www.domainame.com took too long to respond". So I've checked the firewall's rules(ok), iptable (INPUT-FORWARD-OUTPUT are in policy ACCEPT), and the netstat command for check if it is in LISTEN Mode and its ok!!!! If I try to digit https://www.mydomain.com its work!!!!! I'm crazying... I haven't other solution. 
PS: The portforward is ok ... The port 80 is forward in my ip server.

EDIT: I've tried to update Ubuntu Server but I have this problem when I try to connect from external network: " HTTP: 504 - GATEWAY TIMEOUT"

Comment: It's a little something called [hairpin NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning). Your router must know to route traffic sourced from internal -> external public ip -> internal properly or it'll not work ...just like that.

Comment: nathan my router is ok because I don't touch it and a fews days ago my website was working!!!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it could be a number of issues.  With more details I might be able to help more. Here's what I would check out:

1. Make sure your DNS entries are correct/haven't expired
2. Make sure your SSL certs are installed correctly, cover all the subdomains in question, and are valid.
3. Since you mentioned https, you should make sure you are also configured to serve requests into your system on port 443 (default ssl port).

I'm not sure if/how you're load balancing, but most of these problems can be worked out with info gleaned from an LB log.

Comment: I've tried to update Ubuntu Server but I have this problem when I try to connect from external network: " HTTP: 504 - GATEWAY TIMEOUT" 
1 - DNS is correct; 2 - The ssl cert is installed correctly; Fews days ago this configuration worked very well ... but today I didn't understand what is changed